# How do I use Mono.WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, mono, gecko

I read through this page twice http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser yet I have no clue how to use it.

There's no assembly nor can I type `using Mono.WebBrowser`. Using it directly also causes an error because it's not found.

Do I need some separate installs and how am I supposed to set it up and running?

I am trying to have a Gecko rendering a page on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Comment: I just had a look at adding a reference and the assembly Mono.WebBrowser is there under packages. I am running version 2.10.6 of Mono and version 2.8 of MonoDevelop for Mac OS X. Which operating system are you developing on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works via COM - yes  you need sepparate installations. It means that you need Mozilla installed.