# Using Mono.WebBrowser on WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, xamarin-studio

I am really confused!! I found this:

[How do I use Mono.WebBrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415340/how-do-i-use-mono-webbrowser)

I am running Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 C# WinForm project.

**Mozilla Firefox** is installed and operational on my computer.

Yet, when I go to **add a reference** to the `Mono.WebBrowser` control I can't find it.

Why?

I have also tried in the Xamarin Packages:

[image: Xamarin Packages]

Update: Further to other link provided I also tried installing the GeckoFX ...

[Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

I have Firefox 47 and the NutGet only went up to gecko45 so I do not know if that is why i still can't find that control.

In addition I had warnings about architectures being different. Had to be x86.

It seems a right headache so I may not bother with this after all.

Comment: Have you installed the mono browser requirements? http://www.mono-project.com/download/ The page you linked says you need Firefox, but I doubt that is the only requirement.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393343/i-want-to-use-webbrowser-control-in-mono-windows-form

Comment: I will look. The important thing is that I can embed a browser control and that it will support xml/xslt just like the Microsoft Webbrowser control.

Comment: I just downloaded the CefSharp project and done a build in both x64 and x86 and I get many warnings and errors.